# Shirking of Log file on Primary Server of Transaction Log shipping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction-log, high-availability, log-shipping

I have a database with size 200 GB Total(mdf+ldf) and Log file(ldf) with 50 GB and 99% unallocated space in ldf file i.e. not being used at all.

We had setup log backups for every 5 minutes, so there no problem with ldf file increasing.

We had setup Log shipping on Prod server(Primary) and DR Server(Secondary)

Now i have a question,

1. Can i shrink the log file of the database on primary to 1 GB?
2. Can i shrink the log file i.e. ldf without changing the recovery model of database to 1 GB?
3. Can i shrink the log file without using NOTRUCATE option, if i use ssms wizard to shrink.
4. Will shrinking cause for log file to grow more after shrinking?

Expedite answers would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Don't do it if it is not causing any issues. It is likely that it will grow again.

Comment: I have a space of 99% unallocated .ldf file, we want .mdf and .ldf to be placed on separate disk drives, so i want to put .ldf file on 20 GB Disk drive, so if i do shrinking will this cause for log shipping to stop.

Comment: No it will not read my answer. BUT i again reiterate don't shrink

Answer (score 3):

> I have a database with size 200 GB Total(mdf+ldf) and Log file(ldf) with 50 GB and 99% unallocated space in ldf file i.e. not being used at all.

Leave it as it is, the space would eventually be utilized without any autogrowth and that would really help your SQL Server transactions, so just DONT shrink.

FYI

1. You can shrink log files on primary server
2. DONT change the recovery model this would break logshipping. Yes you can  shrink without changing recovery model
3. The log file will eventually again grow so there is no sense in shrinking.
4. You may use `NO truncate` but normal shrinking would just do fine. This is just to answer your queries I would still say do not shrink.

Further reading [Why Does Transaction Log file Growing and Runs out of the Space](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space)

Comment: Thank you, We have a frequent log backups which will control increase of log file (ldf) growth, and i greatly appreciate for answering all 4 questions and helping me to learn.